# How do I eliminate identical/duplicate arrays across multiple rows, in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the follow data:

| Business | MyArray |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | a |
|  | b |
| ID1 | a |
|  | b |
| ID1 | c |
|  | d |
|  | e |
|  | f |

Notice that the first two `Business` rows hold the exact same data `[a,b]`. I'm interested in constructing a query that can screen out the duplicates, such that I will end up with:

| Business | MyArray |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | a |
|  | b |
| ID1 | c |
|  | d |
|  | e |
|  | f |

I'm sure there's a simple way to do so, but the solution eludes me since you can't `group by` an array column.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you consider `[a, b]` and `[b, a]` as duplicates ?

Comment: Yes, but it should be sorted in a way so that doesn't happen

Comment: I see, I've updated to answer to deal with unsorted array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array as a **GROUP BY** column by converting it as a string.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'ID1' AS Business, SPLIT('ab', '') AS MyArray UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID1', SPLIT('ab', '') UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID1', SPLIT('cdef', '')
)
-- query starts here
SELECT Business, ANY_VALUE(MyArray) MyArray 
  FROM sample_table
 GROUP BY Business, FORMAT('%t', MyArray);
```

**query result**

[image]

---

[Update] You can use below query as well if `MyArray` is not sorted

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'ID1' AS Business, ['a', 'b'] AS MyArray UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID1', ['b', 'a'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID1', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
)
-- query starts here
SELECT Business, ANY_VALUE(MyArray) MyArray 
  FROM sample_table t
 GROUP BY Business, (SELECT STRING_AGG(e ORDER BY e) FROM t.MyArray e);

-- query result will be same as above
```